# How to make maven bundlor to use my MANIFEST.MF instead of using a template and types detection?

Tags: maven, osgi, bundlor

I am developing an OSGi app with Virgo, and using maven bundlor to build the bundles. I want to use my `MANIFEST.MF` used by Virgo which includes bundle imports and a few package imports, but bundlor auto detects the classes used by my bundle and generates packages imports for them including the ones from the bundles in `Import-Bundle` header.

Is there a way to tell bundlor just use my already built `MANIFEST.MF` or disable the java type auto detection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, just don't use bundlor then? Like said in the documentation, "Bundlor's main function is to scan an existing JAR file and determine its runtime dependencies.",

For example, with maven-bundle-plugin (in this example, I have a .war file, but that shouldn't matter)

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
          <!-- add the generated manifest to the war -->
          <manifestFile>${project.build.outputDirectory}/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</manifestFile>
        </archive>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>true</failOnMissingWebXml>
        <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/web.xml</packagingExcludes>  
    </configuration>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>bundle-manifest</id>
        <phase>process-classes</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>manifest</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <supportedProjectTypes>
          <supportedProjectType>jar</supportedProjectType>
          <supportedProjectType>bundle</supportedProjectType>
          <supportedProjectType>war</supportedProjectType>
        </supportedProjectTypes>
        <instructions>
            <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
            <Bundle-ClassPath>.,WEB-INF/classes,{maven-dependencies}</Bundle-ClassPath>
            <Bundle-ManifestVersion>2</Bundle-ManifestVersion>
            <Embed-Directory>WEB-INF/lib</Embed-Directory>
            <Embed-Dependency>*;scope=compile|runtime</Embed-Dependency>
            <Embed-Transitive>true</Embed-Transitive>
            <Import-Package>
              javax.annotation,
              javax.servlet;version="[2.5,3.0]",
              javax.servlet.http;version="[2.5,3.0]",
              org.osgi.service.http,
              org.osgi.service.packageadmin,
              org.osgi.framework;version="[1.5,2.0)",
              org.jboss.logging;version="[3.0,4.0)"
            </Import-Package>
            <Private-Package>fi.eis.applications</Private-Package>
            <Web-ContextPath>/spring-app</Web-ContextPath>  
        </instructions>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I could've left the maven-bundle-plugin also undefined and just placed a manifest file in WEB-INF.

Comment: yes you are right, I don't need bundlor actually, was confused and forgot the fact that I only need to build a jar with my MENIFEST.MF, so just the maven jar plugin is enough. Thanks.